# storing key from hash in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I have a list of key-value pairs and I am trying to store the key N times in another array. 
I'm struggling with the logic, if I iterate over the `list_of_objects` I can't see a way to keep track of which keys-values have already been assigned.

```
var kv={"a":2,"b":1,"c":1};
var list_of_objects=[bob,bill,jane,joe];//these are objects
```

GOAL

```
bob.kv="a"
bill.kv="a"
jane.kv="b"
joe.kv="c"
```

Notes in response to comment: `kv` is a property of the object bob (or bill, or jane, or joe)

Comment: Really not clear what you want to achieve. What is the relationship between `kv` and `objects`?

Comment: @Saravana I added a note to my post. Did that explain it better?

Comment: To be clear, it looks like bob.kv=a and bill.kv=a because the value of a in kv is 2 and those are the first two objects in the array, is that correct?

Comment: Yep, thats it exactly

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(kv).forEach(function(key) {
  var val = kv[key];
  while(val-- > 0) {
    var obj = objects.shift();
    obj.kv = key;
    console.log(obj)
  }
});
```

Comment: Excuse the use of `shift` if you didn't want to modify the objects array, I was just keeping the example brief.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @MatUtter's answer but does not mutate the `list_of_objects` array:

```
var index = 0;
for (var key in kv) {
    if (kv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = kv[key];
        while (val-- > 0) {
            list_of_objects[index].kv = key;
            index++;
        }
    }    
}
```